# Read array in chunk order - approach needed

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm, function

I have some array which have stored data in chunk order. The following image illustrates my problem:

[image]

The red rectangles mark the chunks. I would like to read big arrays in this order. For example an array with  16x16 chunks, each with 16x16 values.
Do you have any examples how I could accomplish this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you know how many blocks are stored in the array?

Comment: Yes I know exactly how many chunk ?x? are in there and how many items each chunk has ?x?

Comment: You need another information: the "interleave": in the image you are "cheating" a little, showing rows that aren't there. The real sequence in memory is (1, 2) (5, 6) (3, 4) (7, 8), (9, 10), (13, 14), (11, 12), (15, 16). You then organize your blocks in "rows" of two blocks.